# Parenthesis style in bibtex citation

Tags: bibtex, lyx, natbib

I am using LyX with `bibtex` and `natbib` for my citations.  However, for some reason when I create the pdf, the citation comes out as Author [year] instead of Author (year).  Is there a way to change the style of the parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `\setcitestyle` command to set this.  This is documented on page 12 of the [natbib manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).  A minimal document is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{round}

\begin{document}
\cite{Test}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

which with `test.bib` containing

```
@Article{Test,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}
```

produces

[image: Sample output]